# How to calclulate the number of lines of text in a div server side in java

Tags: java

I need to calculate the number of lines some saved text will require when displayed.

The text will, ultimately, be displayed in a div 500 pixels wide - the added complication being that the text can contain `\n` ('s) so I must factor those into the line number calculation also.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure, you need to solve this on the server side? Can you explain a bit more about the problem. Maybe it's possible to solve this on the client..

Comment: Working on a fixed number of pixels may not be enough, you must take font size/family into account as well. You should work with a UOM relative to the font (em, pt).

Comment: Include the inner padding of the `<div>` in the calculation. Also you will probably need to take different browser versions into account.

Comment: :-) like the mars comment, The exact number of lines are to be persisted along with the text the information will be used to calculate document length. The requirement is different categories of text will have different widths but the client must display the accumulated info one A4 page at a time to reflect the hard copy document - produced via PDF.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't think I understand your requirements. What I understood: You want to display some text on a webpage the same way it will be displayed in a seperately produced PDF split by pages. Correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Font font = new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12);
FontMetrics fontMetrics = getFontMetrics(font);

String text = "a line\nanother line\nsome more line";
String[] lines = text.split("\n");
int lineCount = lines.length;

for(String line : lines) {
    int width = fontMetrics.stringWidth(line); 
    lineCount += (width / 500) > 1 ? (width / 500) - 1 : 0;
}
```

Change the font settings (font-family, style, size) to your settings.

Comment: That is only correct, if the font used on the website has the same metrics. (Serif is not a fixed font name and will be substituted on many systems anyway.)

Comment: Hi. I need to include the \n line breaks in the line count also. So if there was a line break the line count would increment by 1 but if the text preceeding it on the line didn't exceed 500 that text would be no longer included in the calculation.

Comment: @user456147: See the changes I made.

Answer (score 0):

assumming you have in in some String:

```
String text = "foo\nbar\baz";
int lines = text.trim().split("\n").length;
```

If you want to count also empty lines at the end, skip `trim().`.

Comment: This doesn't address the width issue though.

Comment: You forgot to take into account, that the text will also have line-breaks depending on the size of the `<div`>, the font face and size, the browser version and the weather on Mars...

Comment: @nfechner - You said it better :)

Comment: It cannot be predicted on server side how browser will wrap the text. It may have different font, different text scaling, different DPI...